# What do you call a flat with a small yard with no roof?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

So I want to bring my dog with myself traveling and I don’t keep my dogs in closed areas with a roof, because he doesn’t like it. So I always look for renting flats with small yards which are not covered with a roof. I have noticed that in some apartments, the first flat has a small yard to itself. What are such flats called?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a ***garden flat***?

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/garden_flat):

> **garden flat**
> <sub>noun</sub>
>
> A basement or ground floor flat which opens on to a garden.

Examples of a *garden flat*:

> [image]
>
> ([Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.apartmenttherapy.com%2Fa-gorgeous-ground-floor-london-flat-opens-onto-a-garden-255036&psig=AOvVaw30SuxN4dUuahNkczZNe8jF&ust=1653154995049000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCJiJwbTQ7vcCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAP))

> [image]
>
> ([Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Frockmystyle.co.uk%2Fgregs-london-flat%2F&psig=AOvVaw30SuxN4dUuahNkczZNe8jF&ust=1653154995049000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCJiJwbTQ7vcCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ))

The flat opens to or has direct access to a garden, which, of course, has no roof.

Comment: Minor note: one might be tempted, to translate "flat" as "apartment" for the US. At least in the northeast, a "garden apartment" is something specific (and has a different meaning).

Comment: @Yorik: I wasn't sure, because OP mentioned both "apartment" *and* "flat". I went with *garden flat* because it is a term that can be found in dictionaries.

Comment: @Justin - If you are going to the US, you will not get what you want with "garden flat" -- people will look at you confused, or think you want six little pots of annuals or vegetables to transplant into your garden.  Try "garden apartment with a fence or wall around the back yard."  Or "apartment or house with a dog fence."

Comment: @Justin yeah, I wasn't sure either, as the OP says "flat with a yard," which is also simultaneously British and North American..

Comment: Should it be opening to garden necessarily? Or could be opening to a none-green place?

Comment: @Sasan: AFAIK, it usually opens to a patio first, then a green place (garden/lawn). Some more examples: [one](https://images.app.goo.gl/okTcazitKe8PUNUd7), [two](https://images.app.goo.gl/Nj9Y7wvrhW74d5DJ8).